# Rendering divs containing html and svg elements to a canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, svg

I want to take a screenshot of a div(container) in my html page. The problem is that the container might contain both html elements as well as svg. I found several ways to render them to a canvas individually, i.e if only html or svg is present, but I could not figure out a way to render the container on a canvas if both of them are present. Any ideas? I'll prefer if the solution is client side.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?  I am facing the same problem currently and looking for a client side solution.